# unable to specify width to my container in listtile subtitle widget

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, listtile

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBHbe.png)

I want to achieve this design, so i used list tile. But when i used container in subtitle it is taking whole width of list tile.

I tried using constrains but that didn't work for me.

And also tried giving with to container.

Comment: Make your own listTile widget means custom ListTile. Because the built-in widget has a specific width height, sometimes we can update or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made custom `ListTile` widget (based on your design) for you.

[image]

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage:
                    AssetImage("assets/firebase-add-data-class.png"),
                radius: 28),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 8,
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Text("Vandor name",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28)),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    width: 200,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Product Promotion",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("View"))
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. But it would be better if you know a way using listile widget.

Comment: I've mentioned you in the comment about the reason. Don't forget to select this answer as useful if it is helpful for you.

Comment: To know more about the whole reason, click on the subtitle property (ctrl+mouse left), or hover on the subtitle property, read Flutter developers wrote code. (Typically a [Text] widget.) Actually, subtitle is a text widget. So We can't implement or add a container under a Text widget.